# An unhandled exception on button click xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, buttonclick, unhandled-exception

I am getting and unhandled exception error while clicking on button which should direct me to my next activity.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
 {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main);  
        Button contactbtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button4);
        contactbtn.Click += Contactbtn_Click;
 }



  private void Contactbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
        StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));
  }
```

> An unhandled exception occured.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. You should try to get the stack trace of that exception and post it. I think that looking at the stacktrace might even help you solve your own problem.

Comment: I think the problem is in Activity1. You should open Exception Setting and Check All options -> Run app again -> Post the exception detail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be in Activity1. 
One possibility of this problem is that you don't set the layout for your Activity(suppose `layout1` is the layout of `Activity1`) while you use `FindViewById`:

```
  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
```

If you don't have this, `FindViewById` will always return `null`.

Comment: @praneet sharma Hi , have you resolved this question?

Comment: no but i already have SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layoout1);  in the activity1

Comment: @praneetsharma   Could you please post a basic demo or code sinppet  so that we can test with it?

Comment: the error was for the init() function declaration before hide keyboard. got it solved by adding     Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);   to the mainactivity